# I am trying to customize the font and background for a list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list app displayed on a SP page but the fonts are small and plain. I am trying to customize the background color, the font, and add a scroll bar to the items(that might be advanced).

I have had success changing the font size using the script editor and embedding the following

.ms-vh2 {
font-size: 20pt ! important; }
.ms-vh {
font-size: 20pt ! important; }

I am new to coding so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following css in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise list view. I got the place holder `div` name of the list displayed and it is, `DeltaPlaceHolderMain`. You can also find it using the browser developer options. Using the below css, I got the reference of the div and applied back color of the `div`,

```
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain {background-color: blue}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the background color of a specific list on a SharePoint page, you need to follow the below steps:

- Find webpart id by pressing F12 on your page and target that specific webpart area. it will look like *WebPartWPQ..*
- Add a script editor on the page and insert the below css:

  ```
  <style type='text/css'
    #WebPartWPQ8{ // Id obtained from above step
      background-color: blue; //background color
    }
  ```

Let me know if this helps.